# library for iOS to split huge binary files by certain sizes?

Tags: ios, file-io

I am looking for the library for splitting (divide) a binary file into multiple files.
If there is 20MB size of file named "test.m4v" in iOS temporary folder (NSTemporaryDirectory()),
I would like to split that to

- test.m4v.000 (7MB)
- test.m4v.001 (7MB)
- test.m4v.002 (6MB)

Something like that (It doesn't have to be '7MB', could be 5MB like that)

[like command line split command.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/split.html), I don't think we can call this command inside iOS app.

Is there iOS (free/paid) library to do that? I might need to just low level access and write it, but I am too lazy to do that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work assuming the file isn't so large that it freaks out at `dataWithContentsOfFile:filename`. iOS might do caching in the background, but I don't know.

```
-(NSUInteger)splitFile:(NSString *)filename chunkSize:(NSUInteger)chunkSize {
    NSUInteger chunksWritten;

    NSFileManager *fm = [[[NSFileManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];
    NSString *newFileName;
    NSRange dataRange;
    for (chunksWritten = 0; chunksWritten * chunkSize < [fileData length]; chunksWritten++) {
        newFileName = [filename stringByAppendingPathExtension:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%03d", chunksWritten]];
        dataRange = NSMakeRange(chunksWritten * chunkSize, MIN(chunkSize, [fileData length] - chunksWritten * chunkSize));
        if (![fm createFileAtPath:newFileName contents:[fileData subdataWithRange:dataRange] attributes:nil]) {
            NSLog(@"Error writing chunk #%d", chunksWritten);
            break;
        }
    }
    return chunksWritten;
}
```

The error checking obviously needs to be more robust.

Comment: That was perfect! It worked as a charm. iOS DOES do background work and I have tried 266MB file to split each 32 MB, and works perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: Does this have any file size limitation? I think the data returned from `dataWithContentsOfFile` will take in RAM and there will be limit.

Comment: Ok, files split. How to concat them now?

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov If you have a question, the comments are not the place to ask it. Please post a question.